# How to use Yii xupload extension without model class

Tags: php, yii, yii-xupload

I am using Yii [`xupload`](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/xupload) extension. But, I don't know, how to use it without model (if this is possible).

I'm trying to use this code:

```
$this->widget('xupload.XUpload', array(
    'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl("site/upload"),
    'multiple' => true,
));
```

But, it throws an exception:

```
XUpload must specify "model" and "attribute" or "name" property values.
```

I then tried another approach:

```
$this->widget('xupload.XUpload', array(
    'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl("site/upload"),
    'name' => 'bulkUpload',
    'multiple' => true,
));
```

But, it shows an error:

```
Undefined variable: name
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if this extension allows uploading files without model. If I get its [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/xupload) correctly, you have to either provide your own model or use included `XUploadForm`  form:

> Using XUploadAction and XUploadForm:
>
> - XUploadAcion adds basic upload functionality to any controller.
> - XUploadForm its a **simple form model to store uploaded file data**

I think, you should follow this way, if you don't have any own model or try to search for another uploading extension, if this one doesn't suit you.